# Put Excel row cells under each other in one column with its serial number repeating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any possibility of formula, to put cells of one row below each other in a column with its serial number repeating in first column of that particular row

For example:

Check this image:
[image: Check this image]

This need to change into below image

Required End Result:
[image: Required End Result]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please tell us what approaches you have already tried. Also, you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your table in **A1** through **D4** *(or below)*, in **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))
```

and copy downwards and in **F1** enter:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$9999,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Gary both formulas working perfectly fine.